# How AVL tree can guarantee O(log(n)) search all the time

Tags: tree

Excuse me if it's a stupid question. I heard that AVL tree has O(log(n)) for search but I do not understand how could it always guarantees log(n) search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because AVL tree is a self-balancing tree that always have at most 1 level difference between child subtrees for all nodes. The height of BST affects its search time. Imagine if you have a BST with linear shape of n nodes. It has n height not the log(n). In this case, searching time complexity is O(n).(worst case of unbalanced tree). In other word, it means that we can also make a tree which guarantees log(n) search time by controlling the height of tree as log(n).